# Constructor B is not called in an A -> B -> C inheritance chain

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, constructor

I have the following inheritance chain:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Foo'

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Bar'
        super(Foo, self).__init__()

class Baz(Bar):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Baz'
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
```

When instantiating Baz class the output is:

> Baz
>
> Foo

Why isn't Bar's constructor isn't called?

Comment: Works for me, but copy-pasting showed messed up indentation in the `super()` line in `Bar`. Is that possibly your problem?

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi: How on earth did this code work for you?

Comment: LOL, probably because I typed it in myself rather than copy-pasting, once I realised the indentation was messed up. My mind obviously corrected the mistakes automagically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The call to `super()` takes the current class as the first argument, not the super class (`super()` works that out for itself). In this case, the following should fix it... note the change to both `super()` calls:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Foo'

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Bar'
        super(Bar, self).__init__()

class Baz(Bar):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Baz'
        super(Baz, self).__init__()
```